# Static Field Gets Reinitialized On Every Request

Tags: c#, static, .net-4.5, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this very strange behaviour in an asp.net mvc 5 app (test app, very basic).

```
 public class MvcConventions
{
    static Dictionary<string,MvcConventions> profiles=new Dictionary<string, MvcConventions>(1);

   public static MvcConventions CreateProfile(string profile)
    {
        if (!profiles.ContainsKey(profile))
        {
            profiles[profile]=new MvcConventions();
        }
        return profiles[profile];
    }

    public static MvcConventions SingleProfile
    {
        get
        {
            return CreateProfile("default");
        }
    }

        /* removed ohter stuff */

}
```

I'm using the SingleProfile property once in global.asax.cs which creates a profile. But then inside a request the *profiles* field seems to be reinitialized so it becomes empty.

I'm running the app only in VS using IIS express. This behaviour started after I moved the app in a different solution. I don't think it has anything to do but it's strange that it worked as it should before moving it.

Why does this behaviour happens? It's like the assembly containing the class is loaded once when the app starts, then discarded then loaded again in another request. Simply put, *static* is no longer **static**.

**Edit**: I set a breakpoint on *profiles* and it hits twice: once for global.asax.cs and another for the first request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it: I had to manually delete everything from /bin folder for every project then reload the solution. For whatever reason it seems to have used both the old and new assembly and probably it used one for global.asax and the other one for the request.